# Data disappears when paginating

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, servlets, fullcalendar

I am displaying menu on `fullcalendar` for specific dates, using *servletjson*.

Whenever I click multiple times on next and previous month the data disappeared.

When I restart my tomcat server, the data come back, but the problem still persist.

Below is my code for rendering the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    editable: false,
    events: "/OmkaraFinal/CanteenManagement"  
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Also, edit your code for a proper presentation so as to enhance its readability.

Comment: see my update code and question.